# How to get request parameters from a servlet init method

Tags: java, servlets

I am writing a Servlet that retrieves request parameters but needs to use them in the `init` method. Since the `init` method would be called before the `doGet` method and since the `init` method does not have a `HttpServletRequest` object as an argument, I don't know how to get the request parameters.

```
public class OpenIdServlet extends HttpServlet 
{
    ...
    ...
    private OpenIdManager manager;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException 
    {
        super.init();
        manager = new OpenIdManager();
        manager.setRealm("http://localhost:8080/OpenIDSample"); 
        manager.setReturnTo("http://localhost:8080/OpenIDSample/openid"); //I need to append the value of a request parameter here...
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

So the question is: is there any way I can get `HttpServletRequest` parameters in the `init()` method of a servlet? If no what other better approach can one use to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Explain what library `OpenIdManager` comes from.

Comment: @McDowell it comes from JOpenID-1.08

Answer (score 3):

The `init` is called once on startup. So you have to live with a partial `returnTo`, and on request handling (doGet/doPost) complete it with the request parameters.

In fact the manager seems to be request dependent and hence should be created in the request - never as field. As there might be several requests. Maybe persisting as session attribute.

Comment: was adding a comment saying the same, +1 ;)

Comment: @Joop Eggen: But the manager refuses to work when I declared it in a doGet() method. Are you familiar with this OpenID technology?

Comment: Known technology, though did not use the jOpenId library. If needed in init, you could give a fixed URL, and on calling getAuthentication in doGet/doPost call setUserPrincipal or set some session attribute. The returnTo would then redirect.

Comment: There are query strings that must be appended to the URL and they can only come from a request parameter. It seems there is no way to get them, I am working on another way though.

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't make sense. There is no request when the init() method is called. It is called during container initialisation.

Do you mean *initial* parameter? They are available via the ServletContext provided as an argument to init().